# quick navigator tips plugin for webpage

Tags: jquery, css

I want to show help as following screenshot on my website, Is there any jquery plugin available for it? if no luck in jquery, is there any other way to achieve this?

[image]

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Chardin.js](http://heelhook.github.io/chardin.js/). This is a simple-to-use javascript plugin for instruction's overlay.

It **will not** give you your screenshot's design, but if you want something fast to develop and pretty, it's a good choice.